# How to validate API in tests with Swagger?

Tags: java, api, validation, continuous-integration, swagger

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have my API documentation be the source of truth and use it to validate the actual Java REST code ideally through integration testing or something of that sort.  We're using the contract first or consumer contract type of approach, so we don't want the documentation to be generated from annotated code necessarily and updating every time a developer makes a change.

One thought has been to use Swagger, but I'm not sure how best to make it be used for validating the API.  Ideally, it'd be good to have the validation occur in the build or integration testing process to see if the real response (and request if possible) match what's expected.  I know there are a lot of uses and tools for Swagger and just trying to wrap my head around it.  Or if there is a better alternative to work with Java code.

Answer (score 5):

Recently, we (swagger-codegen community) start adding automatic test case generation to API clients (C#, PHP, Ruby). We've not added that to Java yet. Here are some example test cases generated by Swagger-Codegen for C#:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/csharp/SwaggerClient/src/IO.Swagger.Test

It's still very preliminary and we would like to hear feedback from you to see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the idea behind. Basically what Swagger lets you describe, is a number of choices. For a PUT on some resource I **potentially** can get responses 200, 400, 404, 500, last three probably with some error payload. But the tests also require a concrete choice -- for this particular input I get this output. To my understanding it is difficult to deduce it from the Swagger definition. Or we are talking about different tests? BTW, the link above is 404'ed

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to deduce the tests from the swagger spec. The auto-generated test cases aim to make it easier for developers to write tests. We've also explored the possibility of using vendor extension to document test cases in the spec but seems like the community is not interested in that at the moment. (I've fixed the link)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try swagger-request-validator:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator

Here are some examples how to use it:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-examples/

Another alternative is assertj-swagger:
https://github.com/RobWin/assertj-swagger

Comment: assertj-swagger supoprt swagger 2.0 only.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Spring Cloud Contract](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html). It offers you a DSL, where you can describe the scenarios (more or less what is the response I get for a given request) and it seems to fit well to what you described as a requirement...

Comment: Does Spring Cloud Contract allow integration with Swagger though? From what I've read, it sounds like two totally different intent and purposes.

Comment: What kind of integration are you thinking about?

Comment: It would be ideal if Spring Cloud Contract were able to read and use the Swagger JSON/YAML files as its basis for validations.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the Spring Framework, I'd highly recommend checking out [Spring RestDocs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs) which allow you to generate

Comment: I'm not looking to generate api docs.  Rather I'm looking to do the contract-first type idea where the swagger is the source of truth, and then validate the request, response, payload, against the swagger to make sure a developer hasn't broken the contract.